# Is this in the past tense? I'm struggling between writing in the past tense but using active words?

Tags: past-tense, present-perfect, passive-voice

The turf wicket at Cook reserve in Bedford has been vandalised on Sunday after diesel was poured liberally across all five cricket pitches, rendering them unusable.

The same pitch was destroyed by vandals in November, 2013, leading Police and the Bedford Morley Cricket Club to believe these are a series of deliberate acts against the cricket club.

The state of the pitch is one of considerable damage, with police noting that marks on the turf that implies a trolley was used to transport the vast amounts of diesel.

Comment: Which part do you mean? This text uses different tenses.

Comment: i'm sorry, i know this sounds so stupid. It's supposed to all be present tense but the active voice. I just don't understand at all. Where have i used tenses other than past tense?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First paragraph:

> The turf wicket at Cook reserve in Bedford has been vandalised on Sunday after diesel was poured liberally across all five cricket pitches, rendering them unusable.

The above sentence is passive (not active), present perfect tense (which is a past tense).

Consider introducing more nouns for the criminals and use them as the subject, making te sentence active voice, such as a change to:

> Unknown invaders vandalised the turf wicket at Cook Reserve in Bedford. The intruders poured diesel liberally across all five cricket pitches, rendering them unusable.

Second Paragraph:

> The same pitch was destroyed by vandals in November, 2013, leading Police and the Bedford Morley Cricket Club to believe these are a series of deliberate acts against the cricket club.

The above paragraph is passive, past tense. You can rearrange the sentence with the same information to make it active.

> Vandals destroyed the same pitch in November 2013, leading police and the Bedford Morley Cricket Club to believe these are a series of deliberate acts against the  cricket club.

Third paragraph:

> The state of the pitch is one of considerable damage, with police noting that marks on the turf that implies a trolley was used to transport the vast amounts of diesel.

This sentence is passive, past tense. Make the pitch the subject of the first clause, and make it active voice. Make the trolley the subject of the third clause, making it active voice. By making the pitch and the trolley subjects, you avoid having to come up with more synonyms for the criminals.

> The pitch suffered considerable damage, with police noting marks on the turf that imply a trolley transported the vast amounts of diesel.

Comment: Thank you, although i'm trying to maintain the 'active' voice, not the 'passive' voice. Is possible to write these sentences in the active voice if it's in the past tense? Or 'present perfect tense'?

Comment: Would marauders be the correct term? They poured diesel over a cricket pitch, i thought marauder was a term reserved for thieves and con men?

Comment: I changed these to the active voice.

Comment: "Marauder" may not be the absolute best, because it does imply some theft. I will change to "invaders". You need enough synonyms for "vandal" do you don't repeat Amy one term too much.

Comment: Ok. Now I have made the change to "invaders" and also made a few other changes, including formatting.